# Webform Module Email - Module Specific Configuration

Tags: webforms

We've built a custom web form module to handle the capturing of contact information on our website. We recently came across the Webform module and are thrilled that it has so many different customization options that we're looking to transitioning over to using it across our entire site.

Before making this move we'd like to test it out using a single form on our site that captures some user data and sends it via an email submission. This data would not be stored within the Drupal database.

Our custom form module uses the Mail System and Swift Mailer modules to handle the sending of confirmation emails and we'd like to leverage the same modules when using the Webform module.

Within the Module Specific Configuration section of the Mail System module we've defined the following:

MODULE: Webform
KEY: ccpa_email_handler
FORMATTER: Webform PHP Mailer
SENDER: Webform PHP Mailer

I assume that the KEY value needs to be associated with the ID of the Email Handler that was defined for the Webform we've put built.

Unfortunately, when using the Test feature to see what the email looks doesn't seem to be working. When I submit the form I see the inline confirmation message but the email never makes it to my inbox.

I'm sure I've got something misconfigured here but I'm grasping at what it could be. I assume it has to be something with the Mail System and Swiftmailer setup so I'm hoping someone is also using this particular type of setup and could offer some insight as far as the setup and configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that you use Swift Mailer for your current setup, but for your test setup with Webform, it seems like you use Webform PHP Mailer.

Try to use Swift Mailer instead and see if that works.

Comment: I left the FORMATTER as **Webform PHP mailer** and changed the SENDER to **Swift Mailer** which displayed the confirmation message correctly but still failed to deliver the email to my inbox.

The Swift Mailer transport settings are using PHP.

Our custom web form module uses PHP to send email so I assume I have to handle the sending of the email the same way. Do i need to create a plugin that captures the submit event for this form and then handles the sending of the email?

Comment: Try to look in the error logs to see if there are any errors.

Comment: Mails have to be set up on the webform look here for info on how to do it, https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/html-emails-from-drupal-webform/.